# Step by step instruction to install Rust and Cargo for mingw with Msys2?

Tags: windows, rust, mingw, msys2, rustup

I tried to install Rust on Cygwin but failed to be able link with mingw. Now I am trying to install it with Msys2. I already installed Msys2 and Mingw. I tried to follow [this wiki page](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust-wiki-backup/blob/master/Using-Rust-on-Windows.md) but I got lost at number 2:

> Download and install Rust+Cargo using the installer but be sure to disable the Linker and platform libraries option.

Is it referring to the "rustup-init.exe" on [the install page](https://www.rust-lang.org/en-US/install.html)? Should I double click to run this file or run it from Msys2? I tried to run from Msys2 and got the options:

> ```
> 1) Proceed with installation (default)  
> 2) Customize installation  
> 3) Cancel installation
> ```

I don't know what to do next.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

The *Using Rust on Windows* page you linked to dates from before rustup replaced the installer as the default option to install Rust. [Installers](https://www.rust-lang.org/en-US/other-installers.html#standalone-installers) are still available, but you should use rustup if possible, because it makes it easy to update and to use multiple toolchains at once (e.g. stable, beta and nightly). If you must use the installer, just select the `x86_64-pc-windows-gnu` installer and follow the step from the *Using Rust on Windows* page. If you're using rustup, read on.

By default, rustup on Windows installs the compiler and tools targeting the MSVC toolchain, rather than the GNU/MinGW-w64 toolchain. At the initial menu, select *2) Customize installation*. When asked for a host triple, enter `x86_64-pc-windows-gnu`. Then make a choice for the other questions, then proceed with the installation.

**Note:** If rustup is already installed, then rerunning rustup-init won't actually install the requested toolchain. Instead, run `rustup toolchain install stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu` if you already have the MSVC-based toolchain. Then run `rustup default stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu` to set the GNU-based toolchain as the default.

Rustup will install the MinGW linker and platform libraries automatically (as part of the `rust-mingw` component) and refuses to let you remove them. If you prefer to use the MinGW linker and libraries you installed with MSYS2, you'll need to create a [`.cargo/config`](http://doc.crates.io/config.html) file (either in your profile directory, i.e. `C:\Users\you\.cargo\config`, or in your project's directory if this configuration is specific to a project). The contents of that file might look like this:

```toml
[target.x86_64-pc-windows-gnu]
linker = "C:\\msys2\\mingw64\\bin\\gcc.exe"
ar = "C:\\msys2\\mingw64\\bin\\ar.exe"
```

Rustup will modify the `PATH` environment variable unless you told it not to. However, MSYS2 resets `PATH` by default when you launch, so when you try to invoke `cargo` or `rustc` from your MSYS2 shell, it might not find it. You'll need to edit your `.profile`/`.bash_profile` script to set the `PATH` correctly (you need to prepend `/c/Users/yourname/.cargo/bin:` to `PATH`).

Comment: First thank you very much for helping me. I need to confirm by rustup  you mean run ./rustup-init.exe file? I added edit to my original question what I tried.

Comment: rustup-init.exe installs rustup. As rustup-init says at the end, you may need to restart your shell (or log off and log back in) to update your PATH environment variable. Then the `rustc` and `cargo` commands should work.

Comment: Francis: I just edited my question. I still got command not found when run either rustc and cargo

Comment: When I run 
`$ rustup default stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu
bash: rustup: command not found`

Comment: I think the issue is at the Path. I cd to .cargo/bin and run ./rustup then it install. Could you please tell me how to edit the PATH of Msys?

Comment: You'll want to add a line like `export PATH="/c/Users/Thang/.cargo/bin:$PATH"` in your `~/.profile`, then restart your shell.

Comment: just a note, install gcc into msys using following command: `pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-toolchain` ( or x86 variant )

Comment: +1 for the `rustup default` part -- it's the part I missed for it to work. I assumed it'd be automatically picked based on the console (similarily to how cmake works, though that's a different language). The compiler errors were fixed with `rustup default` though

Comment: I have been looking for this for a year, I kid you not... It'd be nice if cargo could tell that one binary was compiled with one toolchain and another by another toolchain...

Answer (score 5):

my problem resolved by following way

1. Run `rustup toolchain install stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu`
2. Second open `.rustup` folder
3. Open `settings.toml` file
4. Change first line with: `default_toolchain = "stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu"`
   done!

Comment: instead of manually editing settings.toml, you can also just use `rustup default stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu`

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a complete guide on how to

**install Rust on windows with Visual Studio Code and MSYS2 MinGW**
on the page found here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/68835925/4230643